# Blobstore Images Disappearing on Google App Engine Development Server

Tags: image, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm using App Engine's high performance image serving on my site, and I'm able to get everything working properly on both my local machine and in production i.e. I can upload an image and successfully display the images using get_serving_url on the blob key. However, these images don't seem to persist on my development server, i.e. after I come back from a computer restart, the images no longer show up. The development server spits out:

> images_service_pb.ImagesServiceError.BAD_IMAGE_DATA

which I'm guessing is actually because the underlying blobs are no longer there (although this is just a hunch). The rest of my datastore is still intact though, as I'm using the launch setting "--datastore_path" to ensure my data persists. Is there a separate flag I need to be using to persist the blobs as well? Or is there a separate problem here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use `--blobstore_path=DIR`:

```
--blobstore_path=DIR       Path to directory to use for storing Blobstore
                           file stub data.
```

You can see all options typing `dev_appserver.py --help` in the command line.