# Life of a Blobstore on the development server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I found this question, which appears to describe the problem I am currently having, i.e. blobstore files do not persist after a restart.

[Blobstore Images Disappearing on Google App Engine Development Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6928416/431176)

However, I believe the question is referring to the python server, and I am running java. I have used the help flag and searched the docs, but dont see mention of the --blobstore_path command line argument. Is there an equivalent for the java server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may or may not be aware, a bug report was filed for this:

[Issue 5449: Blobstore objects not accessible after development-server restarts](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5449)

This was *fixed* on Feb 9, 2012 so upgrading to the latest version of the App Engine SDK should resolve this for you.